# Can I use Host name of a server instead of IP adress in Jmeter test

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, performance-testing

I am trying to load test a website using jmeter, Can i give Hostname of that server instead of ip address in http request default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can. JMeter will resolve hostname into IP address internally.

Comment: ok, actually I am able to access the page i want to hit by giving hostname, but further Logging in is not happening.and same work flow is working when i provide ip address. what may be the problem?

Comment: If you can access the server using host name (from your browser) it means that DNS is working fine and that it shouldn't be any difference between accessing it using IP and host name.

Comment: yes, but that is the problem i am facing. Dont know what is going wrong. :(

Comment: the problem may be with Host header handling in the server. E.g. apache with virtual host settings may ignore requests for different addresses.